# How "this" works in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Can somebody please explain how "this" works in jQuery. I tried to find some information on the net, but because "this" is used a lot in his usual meaning I couldnt find anything good.

I would like to be able to change the background of a list element (`<li>`) onclick without giving each list element an id.

Comment: What about your all time friend, Google? http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Comment: this is more related w/ javascript...try googling for the javascript "call" & "apply" functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("li").click(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "red");

});
```

Here is an example. `$(this)` refers to the JQuery object, `this` refers to the regular DOM object that was clicked on.

Comment: lol, I saw the alert of you posting just before I submitted mine, scrolled down and we had both picked 'red'. I like.

Comment: Haha, I always choose red for examples because it is the shortest :D

Comment: well, there's "tan" too, but R E D are just so darn conveniently close together ;)

Comment: Should I add the id of the UL element in front - $("#udid li") ... will there be any performance improvement?

Comment: the performance loss or gain is negligible, so I would not worry about that, looking up by id is the fastest way tho, but I think your selector should then b $("#udid ul li")

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li').on('click.namespace', function() {

   console.log(this);    /* this is a reference to the DOM 
                            element you clicked */

   console.log($(this)); /* this is a jQuery reference to the 
                            DOM element you clicked */

   /* using jQuery reference you can change the background in this way */
   $(this).css('background-image', 'url(...)');




});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you find the [click() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/)? It shows how you should use the click handlers **and** it has examples that even use `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).attr("class", "clicked");
});
```

When one clicks on an item, `this` takes the value of the item being clicked on, that is the DOM element. `$(this)` gives you access to the jquery API.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the onclick event on the li you can use $(this) to get the jquery object of the li, and then add a class eg. $(this).addClass("newBackground").

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is kind enough to set the context of your function to the thing you're interesting in. In this case the `<li>` in question. But `this` is still a naked DOM element, you need to wrap it with `$()` to use jQuery methods on it.

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({background:'red'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to use a bound function (see `jQuery.proxy()`) as an event handler, in these cases you can access the current element differently, instead of `this`, you can use the `event.currentTarget` property, see http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/